# Cmd/ batch procedure log won't show sql log

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch procedure that calls a sql script.
Inside the cmd it is asked to print the log of sql queries:

```
sqlcmd -i %workdir%\scripts\name.sql -S %service% -d %code% -E >> %toLog%
```

Inside the sql scripts there are 7 queries and all of the are executed but in the log I see only one row of output, for example:

```
(1 rows affected)
```

This problem happens only in Production because in local everything is ok... as usual :)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does it provide the output to terminal if you removed the redirect to log file? Are you running this as a scheduled task? What is the content of the `%tolog%` variable?

Comment: Try running `where sqlcmd` - how many things are in the path that could be executed instead of `sqlcmd.exe`?

Comment: @Gerhard I don't have access to the terminal output, that's why I need it in the log file.
Yes, it is a scheduled task.
`%tolog%` is the name of the log file. 
I repeat that it works as it should in other environments

Comment: so it is just the logfile name, no path. When you launch a script from task scheduler the working directory will be `c:\windows\system32` unless you have set the `start in` section. The script has no idea where you intended to put the file, so you need to tell it where it should be. i.e `set "tolog=C:\Some path\to\log\file.log"` then redirect to `>>"%tolog%"` including double quotes. Also setup the full path instead to `sqlcmd.exe` in case it is not in path, or if another file in the workdir has a similar name. i.e `sqlcmd.bat`

Comment: @Gerhard I am sorry but not understanding the purpose of your question I gave a wrong answer. `%tolog%` is equal to `C:\path\fileName` and as I mentioned before it is writing there some other logs that are before and after the execution of the sql

Comment: then it is probably creating an error, redirect stderr to stdout so you can see errors. `>>"%tolog%" 2>&1`

Comment: @Gerhard Thank you, I will try that.